# Div click event doesn't rise when it is over iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a div element, which has a click event.
When div is over iframe area (div is closer to user than iframe), click event doesn't rise!
If div is somewhere else (not above iframe) - it rises.

P.S.1. Iframe is YouTube video (another domain)
P.S.2. When it is input[type="button"] element instead of div - click rises!
P.S.3. Why div, not button? I need to realize drag event with div (and another element) and it is impossible to do whis button.

I tried:

- transparent screen overlay between div and iframe - nothing;
- find who intercepts click event - nothing.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with the code please?

Comment: The click is probably being applied to the iframe and not your <div /> element. Ensure the DIV has a higher z-index than the <iframe />. Also, if it's an older version of IE, the iframe is an active X control, and because of that I think it will always take precedence. What browser is the issue occuring in?

Comment: I tried and with z-index. z-index of div is 9999, iframe has 10 or something like this

Comment: It doesn't work it all browsers (Chrome 38, for example)

Comment: example http://stackoverflow.com/a/26783221/551744 works... Maybe experiment too clean. Of course I have not only div and iframe. Div is on dragble element, and iframe creates by third-part plugin... Hm...

Comment: So did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add wmode, it  has two parameters.

```
&wmode=Opaque

&wmode=transparent
```

ie,

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lzQgAR_J1PI?wmode=transparent"
 frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque">
```

Have a look [HERE](https://www.scorchsoft.com/blog/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix/)

or jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('iframe').each(function(){
       var url = $(this).attr("src");
       var char = "?";
       if(url.indexOf("?") != -1){
               var char = "&";
        }

       $(this).attr("src",url+char+"wmode=transparent");
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this and it works [perfectly](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/emj283d7/):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wynQl0fD3o8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; background: red; padding: 20px;" onclick="alert('a')">button</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it was. Experiment shows, that when situation is clean - it works. When I create iframe with help of plugins - doesn't. I changed div to button and it works. It is not the same I wanted, but in my case it is the single way.